# Sharepoint Foundation 2013 - getting currently logged on user and passing it in url string/page viewer

Tags: 2013, web-part

I am migrating our existing wss 3.0 site to sharepoint Foundation 2013. Everything is complete but this one item.

We have a Filemaker DB in house that also has a custom PHP frontend. I have a page created in SP 2013 with a Page Viewer Web part that i embed the URL in for the PHP - Database website.
I have always used the following url to grab the currently logged in user from sharepoint and pass it to my php for user tracking.

```
http://webaddress/database/start.php?userName=_LogonUser_
```

This has always worked is WSS 3.0 - it would pass the "domain\username" to my php script that would parse it.

Now with SP 2013 - when i run this same URL - it returns nothing. I am at a loss. I have tried various fixes that i have run across through googling - but my coding experience is null and as much as i have read, this should still work?

Comment: Wow, have you given any thought to the security concerns associated with passing a user name in your URL?

Comment: The security concern on this is not critical. This is an internal only access page and our company is small.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the `_LogonUser_` token is only present in WSS 3.0 and SharePoint 2010. It does not appear in SharePoint 2013

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415880(v=office.12).aspx

In SharePoint 2013, you can use the newly introduced `_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName` JavaScript variable to get the `domain\username` of the current user.

---

One thing to note is that this variable was introduced very recently in SharePoint 2013 Online and might take some time (updates) to reach the on-premise version. So please check if you have this available.

Unfortunately if it's not available, you will have to make an AJAX call to get the loginname of the current user:

http://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/sharepoint-2013-get-current-user-loginname-using-jsom-rest/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

function GetCurrentUser() {
var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";

var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

$.ajax({
  url : requestUri,
  contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
  headers : requestHeaders,
  success : onSuccess,
  error : onError
});
}

function onSuccess(data, request){
  var loginName = data.d.LoginName.split('|')[1];
  alert(loginName);
}

function onError(error) {
  alert(error);
}

GetCurrentUser();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. If that variable is accessible to me, would i append the url like so? http://webaddress/database/start.php?userName=_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName

Comment: how would i go about adding this to the database.aspx?

Comment: You have marked the question as answered. I hope it is working?

Comment: I was unable to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

I am going to Necro this question, and post the .Net implementation for getting the current SharePoint logged in user.

```
var usr = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
```

This returns a `SPUser` object that you can then get the pieces of information pertaining to your situation.